# Why are Strings not colored in the editor?

Tags: java, string, editor

In all the editors I have tried variable declarations usually have color highlighting. int, char, double, etc.. are all colored. Except Strings. Does it have to do something the concept of a String? That is is not considered similar to other variable-types?

```
String randString = "A random String";
```

Here it is actually colored.

I am talking about Intellij, VIM, Sublime Text for example..

Comment: Which editor do you mean exactly? Eclipse for example shows the strings in blue.

Comment: because here `String` is a class not data type

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming really. Just the way some text editors are designed...

Comment: Most likely, your editor uses a different colour for the names of reference types (such as `String`) from that which it uses for the names of primitive types (such as `int`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `String` completely differs from `int`, `char` and `double` cause it's a class while these are primitives.

Second, you should read the specification of each specific editor or IDE to learn about it's conventions, for example [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

Because , only reserved keywords are coloured in every IDE to make sense that programmer cannot assign these names to any variables of method or any other user-defined members.
and String is not a reserved word, it is a class in Java API , so it is not coloured.